# How to translate the verb "develop" (w.r.t. software)?

Tags: single-word-requests, information-technology

Developing software encompasses more than just programming it. It may involve

- determining / defining requirements and/or goals
- planning
- software architecture
- automated testing (which usually involves programming of tests)
- implementation (the programming of the software itself)
- manual testing

and various other related tasks.

Is there an Esperanto verb that can be used to encompass this whole multi-faceted process and refer to it as a whole, just like "develop" can be used in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would still suggest **programi**.

[Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/) does suggest *programi* as [a translation for "to develop"](https://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=develop). [PIV](http://vortaro.net/) gives as [a definition for *programado*](http://vortaro.net/#programado): "La verkado k ankaŭ la projektado, provado, dokumentado k vartado de komputilaj programoj". Given that, I think it encompasses more than just the actual act of coding, and could in fact be used as a word to describe the whole development process.

Answer (score 1):

disvolvi is a good option that I tend to use. Vincent is right though that generally programi is the better option.

Comment: Can you explain how "disvolvi" and "programi" differ in meaning and/or use (when applied to making software) and why "probrami" "is the better option"?

Comment: "disvolvi" means to develop, but in a broader sense. A plant, an animal, an idea, a country, all are things that one can "disvolvi". It also literally means something like unroll/unreel. In the context of software, "programi" is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents…

*Disvolvi* is a more broader term, as Eduardo pointed out. *Programi* encompasses more than just writing the code, as Vincent said. What may throw people off, is that many limit the English verb "to program" to mean only writing code, *kodi* or *skribi kodon*.